# Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException kotlin.Unit coroutines

Tags: android, kotlin, sdk, kotlin-coroutines

Anyone has a clue on how to solve this. I have check online but no helpful resources.

```
   internal fun initialize(args: Map<String, Any>, completion: () -> Unit, error: 
      (Exception) -> Unit) {
    // it crash at this point
    coroutineScope.launch {
        //I have some code here


          val merchant = onennApi.getSelf {
            error(onennException("Could not get reader settings", it.message))
        }?.merchant ?: run {
            error(error(onennException("Could not get reader settings", "Merchant object is null")))
        }

      }
  }
```

Here is the crash log.
It crash at the point of initialisation

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: kotlin.Unit
   at com.client.onenn.onenn$initialize$1.invokeSuspend(onenn.kt:70)
   at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
   at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8669)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)
```

Comment: It seems the error on the other line of code, please post all the code.

Comment: I have updated the log